# website hit counter using php is not working

Tags: php

I made a website hit counter using php , this counter is working fine on local host.

But not working, when I put it on my website. suppose I started couunter.txt with 100 then it will show 101 once and and remains same 101 for next hits.

```
<?php
    $handle = fopen("counter.txt" , "r");
    $counter = (int) fread($handle , 10);
    fclose ($handle);
    $counter++;
    echo "<span style='color:white; font-size:12px;'> $counter </span>";
    $handle = fopen ("counter.txt" , "w");
    fwrite($handle, $counter);
    fclose ($handle);
?>
```

Comment: This is a terrible way to keep a counter... Anyway: are you sure you have write permission on the file?

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be to start sessions for each user that visits the site, and increment the counter value for each session started by him.

```
    <?php
session_start();
$counter_name = "counter.txt";


if (!file_exists($counter_name)) {
  $f = fopen($counter_name, "w");
  fwrite($f,"0");
  fclose($f);
}


$f = fopen($counter_name,"r");
$counterVal = fread($f, filesize($counter_name));
fclose($f);

// Check if he has visited

if(!isset($_SESSION['hasVisited'])){
  $_SESSION['hasVisited']="yes";
  $counterVal++;
  $f = fopen($counter_name, "w");
  fwrite($f, $counterVal);
  fclose($f); 
}

echo "You are number $counterVal";

?>
```

Comment: do i need some change in server ?

Comment: Nope. Just make sure your hosting supports PHP. And btw, this is based on sessions. If you want to make it such that you don't EVER want the same user to be counted twice, you'll need to implement cookies.

Comment: this code is also not working ! after putting this code on my website i checked it on 3 systems but getting the same hit no.

Comment: Could you provide a link to your site?

Comment: On my site I included this within my html page. 
<?php include 'count.php';?> Where count is my php file name

Comment: www.iitk.ac.in/tkic/teqip.htm

Comment: This is exactly what I use on my site. Check your file permissions. Maybe its not letting you read or write to the file. You might wanna change it to a .php extension if you're gonna use include .php - teqip.php